# Google Apps for Work - How to create an upload forms that send file to SuperAdmin Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-sites, google-forms

I am in the 30day try period of Google Apps for Work and i need to create a FORM accesible from all User of Domain, but I can't do it with Google Forms or Google Sites so I follow this [guide](http://www.labnol.org/internet/receive-files-in-google-drive/19697/)

I try this with my personal account and it works, but when i repeat the process with GApps SuperAdmin accounts it doesn't work, I got this error: **Exception: Access Denied: DriveApp.**

Google Script

```
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {
  try {

    var dropbox = "Student Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    } 
    else {
        folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();
  } 
  catch (error) {
      return error.toString();
  }

}
```

HTML

```
    <form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
    </form>

    <div id="output"></div>

    <script>
       function fileUploaded(status) {
          document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
       }
    </script>

  <style>
     input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
  </style>
```

This is My "Deploy as Web App" configuration: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kf-RRR7YZuR2lOVkJLMWRPQ0U/edit?usp=sharing)

I am open to every advice it is not necessary to use Google Script if there is a more reliable road

Comment: run the doGet from the script editor to get the authorization request dialog

Comment: Already tried, the guide I follow explain this step

Comment: Is the Allow 3rd Party Drive Apps setting turned on in your domain?

Comment: Where can i find this settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code, and it worked for me after turning on the Google drive apps @Greg mentioned in one of the comments.

For this setting in the Admin console go to:
Google Apps > Drive > General Settings > and then check the box of "Allow users to install Google Drive apps"

Also with this code the files will be stored in the current user's drive and not in the admin's drive. To fix it you have to to the following:

- Create the file in the admin's drive
- Copy the folder ID
- In the Appscript use the method
     'var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('Folder ID');'
  -you won't need the code to create the folder as it's already done here
- The folder need to be shared with the users
- The users will need to request permission access

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link, it uses google picker within apps script enviroment - so provides a nice slick user interface with progress bar ect..

the main **caveat** is that selecting a specific upload folder requires that multiple uploads is enabled

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs

you would need to change it slightly to add upload view as detailed below.

```
function createPicker(token) {
    if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
      var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView();
      uploadView.setParent(FOLDERID); //PUT FOLDER ID HERE!!!
      var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
          // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
          // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED) //disable this and documents will end up in users root directory
          .addView(uploadView)
          // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
          .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
          // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
          .hideTitleBar()
          .setOAuthToken(token)
          .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
          .setCallback(pickerCallback)
          // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
          .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
              DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
          .build();          
      picker.setVisible(true);
    } else {
      showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
    }
  }
```

My particular use-case was a single upload so I had to write some additional code to move the file to a specified folder - its easy enough tho :)

When testing as web app make sure to use the Test web app for your "latest code". - Found under **PUBLISH -> DEPLOY AS WEB APP...**

When you're ready to share you will have to create a new version and publish that one! This caught me out and isn't really that obvious if your new to it :D - Found under **FILE -> MANAGE VERSIONS...** and save new version then **PUBLISH -> DEPLOY AS WEB APP...** and select the new version from the dropdown list.